# Product of two generating functions in terms of the ordinary generating function? (recurrence relation solving)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, cauchy-product

I have the following recurrence relation that I am trying to solve:
$a_0 = 1$

$$ a_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i$$

for $ n \geq 1$. Let's define $A(x) = \sum_{n= 0}^\infty a_nx^n$, so multiplying the recurrence above by $x^n$ and summing over $n \geq 1$ we get the following $$ A(x) - a_0= \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i\right) x^n$$ and I am quite stuck on how to continue from here, now I know that $$ \frac{xA(x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} a_i\right) x^n $$ but I'm stuck on how to evaluate the expression with the $i+1$, may anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing this approach yields
\begin{align}
A(x)-a_0&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i\right) x^n\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)a_i \sum_{n=i+1}^\infty x^n \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)a_i \frac{x^{i+1}}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)a_i x^i  \\
&= \frac{x}{1-x}\cdot \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^{i+1}  \\
&= \frac{x}{1-x}\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x A(x))  \\
&= \frac{x}{1-x} (x A'(x)+A(x)).
\end{align}
So $$A(x)= \frac{1-x+x^2 A'(x)}{1-2x}.$$
But solving this differential equation doesn't look straightforward.

---

Let's instead obtain a simpler recurrence.  We have $a_0=1$ and $a_1=(0+1)a_0=1$.
For $n \ge 2$,
$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (i+1)a_i+n a_{n-1}= a_{n-1}+n a_{n-1}=(n+1) a_{n-1}.$$
Iterating yields
$$a_n = (n+1) a_{n-1} = (n+1)n a_{n-2}=(n+1)n(n-1)\cdots 3 a_1 = \frac{(n+1)!}{2}$$ for $n \ge 2$, and this formula also works for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @RobPratt's answer, the differential equation$$A(x)= \frac{1-x+x^2 A'(x)}{1-2x}$$ is not the most pleasant but it can be solved.

Let $A(x)=\frac {B(x)}{x^2}$ to get
$$B(x)=x^2 \left(B'(x)-x+1\right)$$ Now, and this has been the most difficult part for me, let $B(x)=e^{-1/x} C(x)$ to get
$$C'(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}} (x-1)$$ which is separable
$$C(x)=c_1+\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+e^{\frac{1}{x}} (x-1)
   x\right)$$ Back to $A(x)$
$$A(x)=c_1\frac{ e^{-1/x}}{x^2}+\frac {e^{-1/x} \text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+(x-1) x } {2x^2}$$

which does not seem to be the simplest way to get the nice result @RobPratt gave in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing
$a_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i
$,
if
$a_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} b_ia_i
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
a_1
&= b_0a_0\\
\text{and}
&\text{if } n \ge 1\\
a_{n+1} 
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n} b_ia_i\\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} b_ia_i+b_na_n\\
&= a_n+b_na_n\\
&= (b_n+1)a_n\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
&=b_n+1\\
\text{and}\\
\dfrac{a_{m+1}}{a_1}
&=\prod_{n=1}^m \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^m (b_n+1)\\
\text{so}\\
a_m
&=a_1\prod_{n=1}^{m-1} (b_n+1)\\
\end{array}
$

If $b_n = n+1$
then
$a_m
=a_1\prod_{n=1}^{m-1} (b_n+1)
=\prod_{n=1}^{m-1} (n+2)
=\prod_{n=3}^{m+1} n
=\dfrac{(m+1)!}{2}
$.

Check.

$a_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_i
$,
so
$a_1
=a_0
=1
=\dfrac{2!}{2}
$,
$a_2
=a_0+2a_1
=3
=\dfrac{3!}{2}
$,
$a_3
=a_0+2a_1+3a_2
=12
=\dfrac{4!}{2}
$.